# Why is it not possible to catch SyntaxError in python?

Tags: python, syntax-error

If I have a block of code like this:

```
try:
    if 45 = 45 : print 45
except SyntaxError:
    print "stuff"
```

When I run it I still get a `SyntaxError`. However, if I do this:

```
try:
    raise SyntaxError
except SyntaxError:
    print "stuff"
```

Then it works as expected (that is, it prints "stuff"). Is it possible to catch a `SyntaxError`?

Comment: You actually get the `SyntaxError` *before* you run the code.

Comment: Code that contains syntax errors cannot be executed. I.e. your `try...except` statement never runs.

Comment: Compiler error vs runtime error

Comment: Yes, and remember there's no *need* to catch syntax errors dynamically, since you fix them all before your code even runs, after which they're gone.

Answer (score 5):

Python isn't 100% interpreted. Your script is compiled to bytecode before it's executed. Syntax errors are detected during this process. If your script is running, it has already been compiled and no syntax errors were found. So you can't catch a syntax error in the executing module. If there were syntax errors, the module wouldn't be executing!

You *can* catch syntax errors in a module you're `import`ing, or code you're executing with `exec` or `execfile` or compiling with `compile`. The usual `try`/`except` around these statements will do the trick.